# unable to add two JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, multiplication, jtabbedpane, jsplitpane

I'm expanding my program, which has no tabs at the moment. I've tried adding to tabs like so:

I declared it:

```
JTabbedPane mainTab = new JTabbedPane();
```

This is how I tried adding the two tabs:

```
mainTab.addTab("Main Tab", splitPane);
mainTab.addTab("Main2 Tab", splitPane);
getContentPane().add(mainTab);
```

This only added the last tab (main2), only one tab gets added.

any help is appropriated :)

Comment: your incredible tour without posting an SSCCE, great question, great answer, isn't it

Comment: @mKorbel The answer was pretty helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A component can only be visible in a single container and it will only appear in the last container to which it was added. You need to create a new `JSplitPane` instance along with new instances of its child components.

Comment: hehehe, please this answer corresponding with +1 for four shots to the dark :-)